# List of CMS (open-source+Java) with build-in wiki module

Tags: java, open-source, content-management-system, wiki

Our group of rookies in Java developing was given a task to build a portal/website for our company, using free open-source Java solution. It must be a website with mandatory 2 sections:

1. section about company's employees (according to Oracle database),
2. section with documentation with version controlling. Actually we need wiki system for this section, therefore i'm looking for CMS with build-in/ready wiki module.

I have read many reviews and articles, but couldn't get much information about wiki. I know that Magnolia and Liferay meet these requirements. But are there any other? (I'm especially curious about Riot CMS).
Thank you!

Comment: I voted to close as this question is far too broad (please read the FAQ). Example - just ask yourself what 'ability to search through content (through "Employees" section)' can mean... (ldap, file system, database, web, facebook, etc.)

Comment: @home Sorry for that. I suppose my bad formulating skills are due to my small developing experience). By searching through "Employees" section, i meant "search through database and display generating search results on the webpage of the "Employees" section.

Comment: where should we be asking question like this in stack exchange universe? I really would like to see if there have been any developments on this-

Answer (score 0):

[XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) seems to have what you need.

- Plugins, API, Programming (easily extensible in development)
- Structured content and inline scripting, which allows building wiki
  applications (easy to add new content)
- Version control (ability to add new articles, with version controlling)
- Full-text search (ability to search through content)
- User rights management by wiki / space / page, using groups, etc. (ability to assign roles to users)

It uses many popular Java frameworks like Hibernate, Lucene and Velocity. Also supports scripting with Groovy so documentation and help should not be hard to find. Also, I quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XWiki):

> XWiki is a free wiki software platform written in Java with a design
>   emphasis on extensibility.

The best part (at least for me) is that it is licenced under LGPL.